# Calling Functions in View Controller for UIImageView Subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

By touching a sublass of uiimageview that I have created, I can call the touchesBegan function within the subclass...but how do I call another function in the original view controller from within that touches began?

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"-- I AM TOUCHED --");


 //need to call (void)selectPhoto in viewController that contains subclass of uiimageview
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using touchesBegan, you should use a UITapGestureRecognizer attached to your image view, and make its target the view controller. Unless there's some other reason you subclassed your image view, there would be no need to do that if you use this approach.

Comment: how do i attach it to the imageView? sorry in advance if this is a stupid question

Comment: @MarkusNotti, sounds like a question from someone who hasn't read the documentation. Please read the UIGestureRecognizer class reference, you'll find the answer there. Make sure you set userInteractionEnabled to YES for the image view, since it's NO by default.

Comment: nvm got it:self.imageChosen.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap)];
    tgr.delegate = self;
    [self.imageChosen addGestureRecognizer:tgr];